# How can I query multiple collections in mongodb at the same time?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, collections

```
books
{
  name: "random",
  stars: 4,
},
{
  name: "random",
  stars: 2,
}

foods
{
  name: "random",
  stars: ,
},
{
  name: "random",
}

movies
{
  name: "random",
  stars: 0,
},
{
  name: "random",
  stars: 7,
}
```

got this collections in my database called dbcosos and I wanna get the items who had more than 3 stars
could someone give me a hand?

Comment: you cannnot query multiple collections at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You can't fetch data from multiple collections in a single query. Instead u can use [find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) in this case to get the required result.

```
let bookData = await booksSchema.find({$and:[{stars:{$exsits: true}},{stars:{$gte:3}}]})
```

Do same thing for `foods` and `movie` collection as well.And `$exists` operator is used since it looks like `stars` is an optional field.